# handle checkbox state in multiple documents on mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to save to mongoDb. I have photos saved in a collection called **Photos**. Each photo has a property in its model called **category**. I'm able to query all images based on category name {category:'portraits'}. Now I also have a property called **isDefault** which is a boolean that represents if this photo should be used as a default photo for this category.

On the front end React side I have a checkbox rendered for each image in a category. This means the user could potentially select 2 or more images and save. So i'm wondering whats the best way to handle this on the server so only one **isDefault** per category is selected at the same time.

I could do a check inside my **edit** and **add** photo functions before I save it. But I feel this is a lot of taxing work to find all "isDefault" per category set them to false and then set a new one to true before saving or updating.

Example of **edit** photo:

```
exports.editPhoto = (req, res, next)=>{

// ADD A LOOKUP HERE TO SET ALL isDefault TO FALSE
  Category.updateMany({ strId: req.body.category }, { $set: { "isDefault": false } })

//then do the find and update the one you want to set to true. 

  Photo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body, {new: true})
  .then(project => {
    res.send(project);
  }).catch(error => {
    res.status(500);
    res.json({message:"Failed to edit project"});
  });

}
```

So my question is there a better approach to solving this or what I'm doing is a pretty good approach. Somehow I feel there is a smarter more officiant approach that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I'm not a pro about it but you could do is bypassing the find part with just setting every picture in the category to `{ isDefault: false }` with `{ multi: true }` and then set the newly selected default one to `{ isDefault: true }`. This way with 2 queries you can achieve what you want to do. Assuming I understood what you were trying to explain right

Comment: You mean bypass findByIdAndUpdate ? But this method is updating a photo with other info along with potentially a change to the check box isDefault

Comment: No I mean you can update multiple records with the same query in mongodb. You don't have to loop each record yourself.